# Dictionary rearrangement and sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Required of counting the number of different values appear in the dict `books`, and in accordance with the number of occurrences of value reverse output.

```
books = {
    123457889: 'A',
    252435234: 'A',
    434234341: 'B',
    534524365: 'C',
    354546589: 'D',
    146546547: 'D',
    353464543: 'F',
    586746547: 'E',
    511546547: 'F',
    546546647: 'F',
    541146127: 'F',
    246546127: 'A',
    434545127: 'B',
    533346127: 'E',
    544446127: 'F',
    546446127: 'G',
    155654627: 'G',
    546567627: 'G',
    145452437: 'H',
}
```

**Output like this:**

```
'F': 5,
'A': 3,
'G': 3,
'B': 2,
'D': 2,
'E': 2,
'C': 1,
'H': 1
```

**I tried it:**

```
import pprint

# to get the values from books
clist = [v for v in books.values()]

# values in books as keys in count,   
count = {}
for c in clist:
    count.setdefault(c, 0)
    count[c] += 1

pprint.pprint(count)
```

**But dict couldn't sorting.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine. You can do this much easier using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collections module to do this for you. Simply pass `books.values()` in to `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(books.values())
print(counts)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'F': 5, 'A': 3, 'G': 3, 'E': 2, 'D': 2, 'B': 2, 'H': 1, 'C': 1})
```

To provide the layout of the output you are expecting in order of value, you can perform a simple iteration using the `most_common` method and print each line:

```
for char, value in counts.most_common():
    print("'{}': {}".format(char, value))
```

Output:

```
'F': 5
'G': 3
'A': 3
'E': 2
'D': 2
'B': 2
'C': 1
'H': 1
```

Comment: To print the counter *exactly* the way OP shows I would implement something like this, using `.most_common()` : `for value, count in counts.most_common(): print("'"+str(value)+"': "+str(count)+",")`

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Sure. I added it to the end of my question, however the `most_common` is not necessary in this case. Seeing that the output is going to be for the entire collection, then simply using the `items` method instead would suffice.

Comment: Cool! Yes, I used `most_common` because in the desired output the items are sorted, and as far as I know this is the most efficient way to print them sorted, there may be a better one for sure!

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar That's hilarious. I *just* noticed it was in order by value! I'm correcting it now. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Why can't I use the Counter class? And returns an error: `get a NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined`

Comment: You should first import it from collections, like `from collections import Counter`

Comment: @Tuto You need to import `Counter` from collections to use it: `from collections import Counter`.

Comment: @idjaw , vinicius Thanks for your prompt.